# Parametric cdf or empirical distribution function?

Tags: nonparametric, model-selection, misspecification

Say I have a set of i.i.d. data and want to learn about the data generating distribution (the cdf would suffice). I could then fit various different suitable parametric models via say maximum likelihood, and use e.g. AIC to choose the most appropriate of them.

But restricting to any of the well known parametric model forms may not always be appropriate and would lead to a bias, and it seems appropriate to simply use the empirical cumulative distribution function. That is robust to misspecification, but as far as I know it has larger variance.

So the question is then, is there a way select the best model among all the parametric options and the nonparametric one?

If I only had one parametric model, a goodness of fit test might do the trick, but that might not work when I have several parametric models? Several QQ-plots may also give some idea, but I prefer a method without personal judgement, and again there is multiple checking involved...

Any ideas? Are there litterature of these or related questions?